# How can I group sequential numbers in a perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to write a perl script in which if I have a sample array which looks like below :

```
@array = (0,1,2,3,4,8,9,10,12,14,16,17,19)
```

then I need to convert/format this array in way so that I get the output in a format which looks like below :

```
output_bus[0-4, 8-10, 12, 14, 16-17, 19]
```

Comment: What's the criteria that specified which numbers should be grouped, and which ones shouldn't?

Comment: @Stevieb , So all the numbers which are continuous they need to be presented in a grouped format. For example : 0,1,2,3,4 are continuous and hence they are represented as 0-4.

Answer (score 7):

```
use Number::Range;
my $range = Number::Range->new();
$range->addrange(0,1,2,3,4,8,9,10,12,14,16,17,19);
my $range_list = join ', ', map join('-',@$_), $range->rangeList;
```

(rangeList returns e.g. `[0,4],[8,10],[12],[14],[16,17],[19]`)

There's also Set::IntSpan, which does more or less the same thing, only with overloading, infinite ranges, and other extras.  Its way of doing this is a little more cumbersome:

```
use Set::IntSpan 'grep_spans';

my @array = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 19);

my $set = Set::IntSpan->new(@array);
my @range_list;
grep_spans {
    push @range_list, $_->[0] == $_->[1] ? $_->[0] : "$_->[0]-$_->[1]";
} $set;
my $range_list = join ', ', @range_list;
```

Here's another way:

```
my $range_list = List::Util::reduce { $a =~ /^\z/ ? "$b" : $a =~ /-(@{[$b-1]})\z/ ? ($a =~ s/$1\z/$b/, $a) : $a =~ /(?<![0-9])@{[$b-1]}\z/ ? "$a-$b" : "$a, $b" } '', 0,1,2,3,4,8,9,10,12,14,16,17,19;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also tell about the package to which Number::Range belongs ? As I am not able to use the above piece of information due to lack of some package !?

Comment: what operating system/distribution are you using?

Comment: which distribution?  "package" means very different things in different linux distributions

Comment: added Set::IntSpan example

Answer (score 4):

Coincidentally I wrote a subroutine to do exactly this as part of my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779141/perl-scripting-using-hashes). Here it is again using your own data as input. The code assumes that the parameters passed are sorted in numerical order

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 19);

printf "output_bus[%s]\n", ranges( @array );

sub ranges {

    my @ranges;
    my ($start, $end);

    for my $n ( @_ ) {
        if ( not defined $start ) {
            $start = $end = $n;
        }
        elsif ( $n == $end + 1 ) {
            $end = $n;
        }
        else {
            push @ranges, $start == $end ? $start : "$start-$end";
            $start = $end = $n;
        }
    }

    push @ranges, $start == $end ? $start : "$start-$end" if defined $start;
    join ', ', @ranges;
}
```

#### output

```
output_bus[0-4, 8-10, 12, 14, 16-17, 19]
```

Or, as [DavidO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716443/davido) suggested in his solution to that question, the [`Set::IntSpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) module does this for you without having to think at all

Here's what a solution using that module would look like. The only discrepancy is that the commas aren't followed by a space, but that can be fixed very simply

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Set::IntSpan;

my @array = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 19);

printf "output_bus[%s]\n", Set::IntSpan->new(@array);
```

#### output

```
output_bus[0-4,8-10,12,14,16-17,19]
```

---

In case anyone comes here in the hope of discovering how to iterate over a `Set::IntSpan` object, the code below works fine. The documentation talks about methods `start`, `first`, `next`, `current`, `prev`, and `last`, but doesn't describe them very well. `start` is a *reset*, while `next` will deliver the next element of the set, until the end is reached when it returns `undef`

This C-style `for` loop iterates over all of the set

```
for ( my $n = $set->first; defined $n; $n = $set->next ) {
    say $n;
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks  a lot :)

Comment: @RaviRaj: You're welcome. Please also check out my alternative solution that uses the `Set::IntSpan` module

Comment: Set::IntSpan doesn't include the requested spaces, and doesn't provide any easy way to iterate over the ranges (or if it does, it is lost in the forest of its documentation)

Comment: @ysth: Yes, I commented on the missing space after commas. As for iterating over the set, it may well be there but I can't find it either. I agree that the POD is poor

Comment: @ysth: The module does support iteration; in fact it does far too much for an application such as this. I've added to my post

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the mention.